# SEAM redirect page from backing bean

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a proper newbie SEAM question, I want to redirect the user to a different page from a backing bean

I know in most cases you should use pages.xml however there could be a number of different pages depending on the bean logic so it seems like it should be a lot easier to do from the bean.

I cant see any examples of people doing this so Im guessing there is a reason why, Maybe something like this would work??...

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
((HttpServletRequest) ec.redirect("http://example.com/");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Redirect component:

```
@Name("yourBean")
public class YourBean {

  @In
  Redirect redirect;

  public void yourMethod() {
     redirect.setViewId("/someView.xhtml");
     redirect.setParameter("someParam", "someValue");
     redirect.execute();
  }
}
```

Or going with FacesManager:

```
FacesManager.instance().redirect("/someView.xhtml", paramMap,
  conversationPropagationEnabled, includePageParams);
```

These only work for other JSF views (ie .xhtml). If you just want an arbitrary URL, you can use the FacesContext as you mentioned in your question.